# what are the grey dashed vertical lines in chrome dev tool performance?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am aware the meaning of those colored dashed lines as said in this [article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/3wS7qVQ6YY8), but what does the gray dashed line mean as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: It's a boundary of an actually presented frame. Should be connected to the frame header at the top.